# Check the redirection address to be the site itself - PHP

Tags: php

I have a multilingual website, the change language functionality works like this:

```
change_lang.php?lang=en&return=www.example.com/pages/etc
```

in change_lang.php I read the `$_GET['return']` and `$return_addr = $_GET['return']` then use `header("location:" . $return_addr)` to send the user back to the place he was, now Imagine someone wants to pollute the return address:

```
change_lang.php?lang=en&return=www.HACKER-SITE.com/virus.exe
```

For preventing this, I want to limit the `$return_addr` value to only local machine(server), my code is:

```
<?php
    if(substr(BASE_URL, 0, 8) == 'https://'){
        $start_len = 8;
        $return_http = 'https://';
    } else{
        $start_len = 7;
        $return_http = 'http://';
    }
    $http_extracted_base_url = substr(BASE_URL, $start_len);
    if(substr($http_extracted_base_url, 0, 10) == substr($return, 0, 10)){
        // OK
    }else{
        // NOT OK
        exit();
    }
    ?>
```

`BASE_URL` is a defined value of my domain, like `http://example.com`, the above code works well when the user is not using "www" in his address, but when he does, I need to check another thing on my code, all of this must have a better solution, and that's my question; how I'm supposed to check if the return URL is going back to the site itself, I don't want to check http`s` r www, or also we may want to have another domain in future parked on our site, so some users may use the second address and the above code fails since `BASE_URL` is defined as the first domain.

P.S: I don't want to `PING` the domain of return address, execution functions are disabled on the server.

Comment: is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` out of the question here?

Comment: Is the protocol and domain name necessary? Could it work if you just sent `&return=pages/etc` instead of the full URL? That would make it simpler.

Comment: @Dale HTTP_REFERER could be manipulated I read somewhere, is that true?

Comment: @behz4d I've only just been told that myself so I don't know for sure.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Ok, imagine we're just doing `&return=pages/etc`, now if a user does `&return=HTTP://hacker-site.com` this will redirect the target user to the `hacker-site.com`, this is not gonna fix anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` or your defined `BASE_URL`

```
<?php

    // your language handling code

    $redirect = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : BASE_URL;
    header("Location: {$redirect}\r\n");
    exit;
```

I will add that while this could be manipulated (so I'm told) surely the only person it would affect is the user that manipulated that header, as they are being redirected?

Comment: using this, still we may need check for www and http or httpS

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is write a function that takes in 2 URLs, one being the `return=URL` and the other being say.. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`/`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`/`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

example:

```
function secure_url($server_url, $get_url) { 
    //do function stuff
    //check URLs to see if the return parameter matches the URL of your site
    //might have to strip any extra URL data for comparison
    if ($bad_url) exit;
}
```

Comment: some users may use 'httpS' instead of 'http', some users may use 'www' on the address and some users may not, some users may use the second domain address, some users may use the first site address, there is really no better ways?